# Combining two PHP arrays with some conditional addition thrown in

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an unusual problem, but I'm fairly certain it's not impossible to solve.
Consider the two arrays below.

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 2 )

Array ( [0] => 879 [1] => 482 [2] => 1616 )
```

I need to add the values in second array where the values in the first array are the same so that I would end up with...

```
Array ( [0] => 879 [1] => 2098 )
```

How might this be accomplished? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And where are you stuck with your code?

Comment: Use the values from the first array as keys to group your values from the second array into subArrays, which you then can sum together.

Comment: use `array_merge()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a full-proof way of completing this task, but it achieves the goal you desire. What's happening here is we're looping through your first array (*the keys*) and using the set values of these keys to add the values from the second array:

```
$new = array();
foreach($keys as $i => $key) {
    if(!isset($new[$key])) { $new[$key] = 0; }
    $new[$key] += $vals[$i];
}
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#8TCLMSyKQ)

**Notes**

- `$keys` being your first array: `$keys = array(1, 2, 2);`
- `$vals` being your second array: `array (879, 482, 1616);`

As I stated, this isn't full-proof. You will need to modify it to ensure integrity, but it is a start that shows the flow of how you can go about doing what you require.

Comment: I've implemented this solution and used it in a quick test. Works like a charm. I can't think of a reason why you would say this isn't fool-proof. Can you please elaborate on your concerns?